# Python 3: N is odd number and greater than - code not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new at learning Python and I have stumbled upon interesting site called HackerRank where you progress by solving task. I have stucked on this one:  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-if-else/problem

Although there are several ways to solve this, I have tried to do it with elif statements as shown in description of task but for some reason, I'm failing to solve this because the last line (elif statement) of my code is not working.

Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
N = int(input())
num = N % 2
if num > 0:
    print("Weird")
elif num == 0 and range(6,20):
    print("Weird")
elif num == 0 and range(2,5):
    print("Not Weird")
elif num == 0 and N > 20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

So everything works until point where checking if number is even and bigger than 20. I have googled and searched and everywhere I looked, this and operator should work but it doesn't in my case. Can anyone help?

Comment: Whatever you mean it to do (that you have not described in your question), `and range(...):` doesn't do that.

Comment: The problem is not with the final condition, but with the ones before it. `range(6,20)` is always true.

Comment: `range(..)` doesn't do what you think it does. Do it this way:  `elif num == 0 and 6 <= N <= 20:`

Comment: Just a side note. Using `range(a, b)` will give you a range from `a` to `b-1`.`range()` gives you a half closed, half open interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of [range](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)(...) is wrong.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    num = N % 2
    if num > 0:
        print("Weird")
    elif num == 0 and 6 <= N <= 20:
        ...
```

Just to use your ideia of range:

```
# The example bellow just work with int numbers and is more slow than the above approach.
elif num == 0 and N in range(2,21):
```

Comment: I think he wants: `if num > 0 and N in range(2, 60)`.  `num` is just used to check if the number is even, `N` is the input number.

Comment: Sorry for that!

Comment: Just to clarify here, as many have not read that actually task and downvoted my question, here is task description:

Given an integer, , perform the following conditional actions:

If n is odd, print Weird
If n is even and in the inclusive range of  to , print Not Weird
If n is even and in the inclusive range of  to , print Weird
If n is even and greater than , print Not Weird

Therefore, I tought my last line is not working...

Comment: Thank you @JoaoVitorino on solving my problem! I have indeed used the range function in a wrong manner.

Comment: @Mittnick Clarifications to your question should be [edited into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50467658/edit), not posted as comments on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   N = int(input())
num = N % 2
if num > 0:
   print("Weird")
elif num == 0 and N in range(2,6):
   print("Not Weird")
elif num == 0 and N in range(6,21):
   print("Weird")
elif num == 0 and N > 20:
   print("Not Weird")
```

I think it should be **N in** range and range(2,6) means [2 3 4 5] 
if you are not use N in range you will get wrong answer. I think it is not about your condition check error it is error about difficult to find out value from range.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())

while True:
    if n==0:
        print("please enter positive integer")
    break

if (n%2) != 0:
    print("Weird")

elif (n%2) == 0 and 2<= n <= 5:
    print("Not Weird")

elif (n%2) ==0 and 6 <= n <= 20:
    print("Weird")

elif (n%2) ==0 and n > 20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem described in the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if n%2!=0:
    print("Weird")

elif n%2==0 and n in range(2,6):
    print("Not Weird")

elif n%2==0 and n in range(6,21):
    print("Weird")

elif n%2==0 and n>20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    num = n % 2
    if num != 0:
        print("Weird")
    elif (num == 0):
        if n in range(2, 5):
            print("Not Weird")
        if n in range(6, 21):
            print("Weird")
        if (n > 20):
            print("Not Weird")
```

Looking at this problem... the range format got me the first time round `(2:5)` rather than `(2, 5)`. Then also the `6, 21` rather than `6, 20` :)